# How can I remove an item by type from a nested list or vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, nested-forms

Is there a way to remove items in a nested list by type such that (1 [2] 3 (4 [5] 6)) becomes (1 3 (4 6)) if I want to remove just the vectors?

Using postwalk, I can replace all vectors with nil, but I can not find a way to remove them.

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk 
  #(if (vector? %) nil %) '(1 [2] 3 (4 [5] 6)))

=>(1 nil 3 (4 nil 6))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Far from perfect but perhaps it is a good start:

```
 (clojure.walk/prewalk #(if (list? %) (remove vector? %) %) '(1 [2] 3 (4 [5] 6)))
```

Comment: This seems exactly what I was looking for.  It did not occur to me that I could perform a function on only the sub-structures.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to see a more concise solution using `clojure.walk`, but here is one which uses a recursive function and `mapcat`:

```
(defn remove-vectors [coll]
  (mapcat
     (fn [x]
       (cond
         (vector? x) nil
         (coll? x) (list (remove-vectors x))
         :else (list x)))
     coll))
```

And one which uses `filter` and `map`:

```
(defn remove-vectors [coll]
  (map #(if (coll? %) (remove-vectors %) %) (remove vector? coll)))
```